# Kotlin - Mockito Test Failing

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, junit, mockito

I have the following method in my kotlin code base

```
package com.service.organization

import com.domain.Organization
import com.repository.organization.OrganizationRepository
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

interface OrganizationService {
    fun listAll(pageable : Pageable , archived : Boolean?) : Page<Organization>
}

@Service
internal class OrganizationServiceImpl(private val organizationRepository : OrganizationRepository) : OrganizationService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    override fun listAll(pageable : Pageable , archived : Boolean?) : Page<Organization> {
        val organizations : Page<Organization>
        if (archived !== null) {
            organizations = organizationRepository.findByArchived(archived , pageable)
        } else {
            organizations = organizationRepository.findAll(pageable)
        }
        return organizations
    }
}
```

I have the following test to test out the archived flow

```
package com.service.organization

import com.domain.Organization
import org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
import java.util.*

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class OrganizationServiceTest {

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockOrganizationRepository: OrganizationRepository

    @Mock
    lateinit var mockPageable: Pageable

    internal lateinit var organizationServiceImpl: OrganizationServiceImpl

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        organizationServiceImpl = OrganizationServiceImpl(mockOrganizationRepository)
        //mockPageable = Mockito.mock(Pageable::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun testListAll_Archived_NoOrgsReturned() {
        val archived = true
        var mockPageableObj = Mockito.mock(Pageable::class.java)
        val organizationList = LinkedList<Organization>()
        val returnedPage = PageImpl(organizationList)

        var exc: Exception? = null
        try {
            Mockito.`when`(mockOrganizationRepository.findByArchived(Mockito.anyBoolean(), Mockito.isA(Pageable::class.java))).thenReturn(returnedPage)

            val organizationPage = organizationServiceImpl.listAll(mockPageableObj, archived)
            assertNotNull(organizationPage)
            assertTrue(organizationPage.size == returnedPage.size)

            Mockito.verify(mockOrganizationRepository, Mockito.times(1)).findByArchived(Mockito.anyBoolean(), Mockito.isA(Pageable::class.java))
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            exc = e
            exc.printStackTrace()
        }
        assertNotNull(exc)
    }

}
```

However when I run that test - I get the following error

```
[INFO] Running com.service.organization.OrganizationServiceTest
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.isA(Pageable::class.java) must not be null
     at com.service.organization.OrganizationServiceTest.testListAll_Archived_NoOrgsReturned(OrganizationServiceTest.kt:139)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
     at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
     at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
     at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
     at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
     at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
     at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
     at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider trying `Mockito.any(Pageable::class.java)` and see if that makes a difference. Though docs show that it is just an alias for `isA`

Comment: You also should add the code that shows how you create that mock and how you inject it into the class under test, as well as a more complete example of the `class under test` including its constructors and fields.

Comment: @second - question updated with full class and test class

Comment: @Nkosi - I get the exact same error when I use any instead of isA

Comment: @second the order in the repository method of findByArchived is different to that of the listAll service method. None the less - I tried this and still the same error -  Mockito.`when`(mockOrganizationRepository.findByArchived(archived = Mockito.anyBoolean(), pageable = Mockito.any(Pageable::class.java))).thenReturn(returnedPage)

Comment: Yeah I noticed, my eyes kept wandering to the wrong place ;) ... its easier to read if parameter order is identical ;)

Comment: Can you clearify the meaning of `!==`? Does that translate to `archived` should be anything but null?

Comment: @second - yes if archived is not null it follows that flow. This is legacy code I have inherited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197722/discussion-between-second-and-damien).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt use a matcher but used the specific value for the method call.

UPDATE

This medium post also highlights a valid solution where you can pass an any() matcher
https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791

Comment: Could you add a short code example for the solution specified in the external link (as links might end up dead at some point of time) ? -- Also if you have the [mre] please post it anyway.